# When I paste an image into photoshop it is blurry

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, image-quality, photography

I open a high quality photo in Photoshop.
I then cut the section I want into another image (I am making a cover photo for Facebook 848 x 315 px). When I paste the image and scale it appropriately it appears to be pixalated when I zoom in. 
I am wondering is it when I set up a new image to paste it to, am I setting it up wrong?

Comment: Are you scaling the image up?  That will always cause "blurriness" (pixelation).  Zooming in will always cause this in Photoshop too, as it's a raster image editor.

Comment: You're scaling your image and zooming, that's your problem. Scaling = loss of quality. Zooming = enlarging the pixels.

Comment: I believe I am scaling the image down. Would this still have the same result?

Comment: @Sfocker scaling your image down means there are literally less pixels so yes, thats your problem. If your image looks ok at 100% zoom then you are ok, no need to zoom in. A raster image is meant to be viewed at its actual size, *any* raster image will look pixelated when zoomed in, thats just the nature of raster images.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure interpolation is set to Bicubic (sharp or smooth) in Preferences:

[image]